# How can I output the slug of a comment author?

Tags: php, comments, author, slug

I'm trying to output the slug of the comment author. I'm able to output the username using `get_comment_author()` but I can'tfigure out how to output the slug.

For example, username might be `Test User` while the slug might be `test-user1`

Howw can I output the comment author slug?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the username then you should be able to get the user using the get_user_by function, which will return the user object

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

```
$user = get_user_by(field, value);
```

Comment: This doesn't help if you don't have the username. I need to output it directly.

Comment: Sorry I thought you said you had the username

'I'm able to output the username using get_comment_author()'